# How to make the facebook share spider not to cache the page

Tags: facebook, caching

I like the share button more than the like button, thats why i'm using it. The problem is that if the title of the page change and when someone paste it into facebook is still with the old title

Sample code

I put span with **a** tag in the bottom of the page

```
http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=http://stackoverflow.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the share functionality is not a good decision since it has been deprecated and is no longer supported, as it clearly states [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/):

> The Share button has been deprecated in favor of the Like button, and
>   will no longer be supported. Please use the Like button whenever
>   possible to drive maximum traffic to your apps.

And [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **What happened to the old Share button?**
>
> We deprecated the Share Button when we launched the Like button,
>   because the Like button improves clickthrough rates by allowing users
>   to connect with one click, and by allowing them to see which of their
>   friends have already connected.

With that said, to answer your question, it also written in the [Like Button guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> **When does Facebook scrape my page?**
>
> Facebook needs to scrape your page to know how to display it around
>   the site.
>
> Facebook scrapes your page every 24 hours to ensure the properties are
>   up to date. The page is also scraped when an admin for the Open Graph
>   page clicks the Like button and when the URL is entered into the
>   Facebook URL Linter. Facebook observes cache headers on your URLs - it
>   will look at "Expires" and "Cache-Control" in order of preference.
>   However, even if you specify a longer time, Facebook will scrape your
>   page every 24 hours.
>
> The user agent of the scraper is: "facebookexternalhit/1.1
>   (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

To clear the cache the easiest thing is to just use the [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug).

Comment: I didnt knew that it change the value every 24 hours. Thats fine, about the **Debug Tool** i can't use it since the urls are dinamic. Thanks for the good answer :)

Comment: So what if the url is dynamic? You can issue a request to the debugger in any way you want, even curl. so you can clear the cache on runtime.

Comment: The url is for users pforile page and in the og:title i show some info then put in .. so i cant refresh the page for all users.. but if it is changing every 24 hours thats fine :) , because the user at some point will edit there info.